# Jenkins "Post Build Action" to deploy zip on Maven repository

Tags: maven, jenkins, post-build

I Have recently started using Jenkins and currently using version 1.492. I have a Maven module project which produces a Jar and a Zip files which I want to deploy to a Nexus Maven repository. 
When I build my project locally I get the message : 
Installing PROJECT_DIR/target/groupID/projectId-version.jar to LOCAL_REPO/ groupID/projectId-version.jar 
Installing PROJECT_DIR /groupID/projectId.zip to LOCAL_REPO/ groupID/projectId/version/ projectId-version-classifier.zip

Using the "Post Build Action" Deploy artifacts to Maven repository. On the Jenkins build logs I can see my jar is deployed but nothing about my zip. 
Is there a specific config to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to do it on command line via **mvn deploy**

Comment: If I do mvn deploy I can see the zip is deploy on the maven repository but if I use  "Post Build Action, Deploy artifacts to Maven repository" on Jenkins the zip artifact is not deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your project to attach additional zip artifact.

```xml
 <project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-artifacts</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifacts>
                <artifact>
                  <file>some file</file>
                  <type>extension of your file </type>
                  <classifier>optional</classifier>
                </artifact>
              </artifacts>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: The artifact attachement is done correctly because I can deploy it by doing mvn deploy, the problem seems to be cause by "Post Build Action" on Jenkins